# What is creating .dll.config

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have several MVC4 web projects.  Recently, some of these projects have started to generate a DLL configuration file.  For example, if I look in the /bin folder, on some of the projects I can see a MyProject.dll.config.

If I look at the backups, these projects have not always generated these .dll.config files.

Can anyone tell me what is causing these files to be generated, and how it can be turned off?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have those .dll.config files added in your projects?

Comment: No, theyt are only visible if I browse the /bin folder.  They don't appear to do anything, i.e. the project still runs as before - I just don't like things added to the build that I don't understand.

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question? I'm experiencing the same problem.

Comment: Hi Anthony, not an answer, but I believe the config files are related to some of the later extensions added into Visual Studio.  They do not appear to be problematical.